# installing PostGIS PostgreSQL 9.1 on windows

Tags: postgresql, postgis

Trying to follow [these instructions](http://www.gpsfiledepot.com/tutorials/installing-and-setting-up-postgresql-with-postgis/) however there is no "Spatial Extensions" in the "Application Stack Builder".

Comment: PostgreSQL version 9.1 is still in Beta. If you think the installer is not complete, send a report to the PostgreSQL project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

9.1 (Last time I checked) doesn't have the spatial extensions in the stack builder, so you need to download and install V9.0

Also note, that the 64 Bit versions don't have them either as PostGis is not yet available in a 64 bit build.

V9.0 32 Bit definitely has them, I've just downloaded and checked about 5 mins ago.

Comment: Ok, if I ever get around to do doing this - I'll revisit this answer.